# How to get the current string from "Class.forName(name).newInstance()" using java 

Tags: java, sql, mysql

this is my code :

```
public static List populate(ResultSet rs, Class clazz) throws Exception {

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData(); 

        int colCount = metaData.getColumnCount(); 

        List ret = new ArrayList(); 

        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields(); 

        while (rs.next()) {
            Object newInstance = clazz.newInstance(); 



            for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) { 
                try {
                    Object value = rs.getObject(i);

                    for (int j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
                        Field f = fields[j];
                        if (f.getName().replaceAll("_", "").equalsIgnoreCase(
                                metaData.getColumnName(i).replaceAll("_", ""))) {
                            BeanUtils.copyProperty(newInstance, f.getName(),
                                    value);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            ret.add(newInstance);
        }
        rs.close();
        return ret;
    }
```

and this is the method to call it :

```
public List getLastAddress(String terminal_id, String last_2) throws Exception {
        String sql ="SELECT a.adress_reality from accounts_location_"+last_2+" AS a WHERE a.terminal_id = '"
                +terminal_id+"' ORDER BY a.time_stamp DESC limit 1";

        System.out.println(sql);
        ResultSet rs = getDr().getSt().executeQuery(sql);

        return populate(rs, Class.forName("hdt.ChineseAddressBean"));
```

and then :

```
List cn_address=sd.getLastAddress(toNomber,last_2);  
System.out.println(cn_address.get(0));
```

but it show :

```
hdt.ChineseAddressBean@f0eed6
```

so How to get the current string  from `cn_address.get(0)`,

thanks

this is my ChineseAddressBean.java:

```
package hdt;

public class ChineseAddressBean {

    String adress_reality = "";

    public String getAdress_reality() {
        return adress_reality;
    }

    public void setAdress_reality(String adress_reality) {
        this.adress_reality = adress_reality;
    }

}
```

**updated1:**

when i use this , it show error :

[image]

**updated2:**

[image]

this is the error :

[image]

Comment: how can you ever print the index without iterating the list.?Have you tried what i suggested.

Comment: Your List is a List<Object> and not a List<ChineseAddressBean>. An Object doesn't have the method getAddress_reality(). You need to cast it to a ChineseAdressBean.

Comment: @zjm1126,how can you ever print the index without iterating the list.?Have you tried what i suggested.

Comment: the sql only retun 1 info .   see the "limit 1"

Comment: @zjm1126,can you post the error which it is showing.

Comment: @zjm1126,Can you try as what i have updated now.

Comment: You need to write it as (((ChineseAddressBean)cn_address.get(0)).getAdressReality().Your updated2 tries to convert string to CAB but it doesn't convert the Object you get from the list to CAB. If you do it in 2 stages you get 1, ChineseAddressBean cab = (ChineseAddressBean)cn_address.get(0); 2, String address = cab.getAddress_reality().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     Object address = cn_address.get(0);      
     ChineseAddressBean chineseaddressbean = (ChineseAddressBean)address;     
     System.out.println(chineseaddressbean.getAdress_reality());
```

The above lines is what you need to do to achieve what you want.Please let me know if its working.

Answer (score 0):

Meybe you need to make method toString () in Your class instance.

Answer (score 0):

`cn_address.get(0)` returns an object, you should convert it to a string

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are getting a list of objects of class "ChineseAddressBean" in cn_address. Right?
Then if you do

List cn_address=sd.getLastAddress(toNomber,last_2);
System.out.println(cn_address.get(0));

It will take the first element in the list and print it.  To print it, it will try to convert it to String by  calling toString method of the object. So if you override toString method in class "ChineseAddressBean" and return whatever you want to print, it will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a `toString()` method in your bean.

```
public String toString() {
   return adress_reality;
}
```

Missed in your example that you need to cast the objects retrieved from your list to the appropriate type.
So:

```
System.out.println((ChineseAddressBean)cn_address.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning `List` you access `Object` (not `ChineseAddressBean`). Also when you print it you call default `toString()` method which returns class name followed by hash code.

You have to return `List<ChineseAddressBean>` or cast the result to `ChineseAddressBean` (which you are doing wrong).

Try this one:

```
System.out.println(((ChineseAddressBean)(cn_address.get(0))).getAdress_reality());
```

You can also write `toString()` method for `ChineseAddressBean` which returns address string and then you dont have to call `getAdress_reality()`.